# understanding xml namespaces

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

Hi im having problems understanding how namespaces and default namespaces are working in xml

In the example below i'm seeing 2 default namespaces (recherche and mots-clefs) and 2 namespaces (xmlns:yahoo and xmlns:yahoo2 am I right?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<recherche xmlns="http://www.google.com/" xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahoo.com/">
  <mots-clefs xmlns="http://www.yahoo.com/">fraise, orange</mots-clefs>
  <yahoo:mot xmlns:yahoo2="http://www.yahoo.com/">
    <nombre>3</nombre> 
  </yahoo:mot> 
</recherche>
```

Comment: For your `yahoo:mot` element, since the http://www.yahoo.com/ namespace is declared in the `recherche` ancestor with the `yahoo` prefix, and is used on that `yahoo:mot`, there is not need to have `xmlns:yahoo2="http://www.yahoo.com/"`. It's just creating another (unused) namespace-prefix bound to the same namespace that is already declared. It's just clutter. Think of namespace-prefixes as variables with the namespace being the assigned value. No need for yahoo and yahoo2 if they have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different namespaces declared:

1. http://www.google.com/
2. http://www.yahoo.com/

There are two namespace-prefixes, both bound to the http://www.yahoo.com/ namespace:

1. yahoo
2. yahoo2

Some of the elements are declared without a namespace-prefix, but still bound to a namespace:

- /*:recherche = http://www.google.com/
- /*:recherche/*:mots-clefs = http://www.yahoo.com/
- /*:recherche/*:mot = http://www.yahoo.com/
- /*:recherche/*:mot/*:nombre = http://www.google.com/

Notice that the `nombre` element is bound to the http://www.google.com/ namespace, because it does not have a namespace-prefix, and the first ancestor that does not have a namespace-prefix `recherche` has the namespace set to http://www.google.com/.

In XPath you can ask what the namespace is for the element using the [`namespace-uri()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-namespace-uri) function.

Due to how namespaces are inherited, it can be confusing (and error-prone) when people have mixed namespaces and do not user namespace-prefixes. In general it's a best practice to apply namespace-prefixes in order to avoid such confusion.

If you are hand-coding the XML, setting the namespace without a prefix can help make it easier to construct the XML and avoid repeating the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the XML maintains two default namespace definitions and two namespace prefixed definitions. Due to the overlapping presence of both, underlying tags have nuanced scoping inheritances.

Per the XML 1.0 specifications regarding [Namespace Scoping](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#scoping-defaulting):

> The scope of a namespace declaration declaring a prefix extends from the beginning of the start-tag in which it appears to the end of the corresponding end-tag, excluding the scope of any inner declarations with the same NSAttName part. In the case of an empty tag, the scope is the tag itself. 
>  Such a namespace declaration applies to all element and attribute names within its scope whose prefix matches that specified in the declaration. 
>  The expanded name corresponding to a prefixed element or attribute name has the URI to which the prefix is bound as its namespace name, and the local part as its local name.

Therefore, while there are two default namespaces in your posted XML, the inner declared default namespace supplants the outer default namespace in scope but only for that specific tag and its descendants.

Moreover, any DOM library methods that intend to parse the content of the root `<recherche>` and all its non-prefix tagged descendants must acknowledge the Google URI. However, *only* for `<mots-clefs>` and all its non-prefix descendants (which are none except a text node) must use the current default namespace scope of the Yahoo URI.

To illustrate further, see namespace scoping comments in an indented version of your XML. Notice the `<nombre>` tag being a descendant of `<recherche>` and not having a colon-separated prefix will default to the first declared default namespace.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                           <!-- NMSP SCOPES: -->
<recherche xmlns="http://www.google.com/" xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahoo.com/">  <!-- GOOGLE URI   -->
    <mots-clefs xmlns="http://www.yahoo.com/">fraise, orange</mots-clefs>       <!-- YAHOO URI    -->
    <yahoo:mot xmlns:yahoo2="http://www.yahoo.com/">                            <!-- YAHOO PREFIX -->
        <nombre>3</nombre>                                                      <!-- GOOGLE URI   -->
    </yahoo:mot> 
</recherche>
```